# C Inline Asm Int 0x10

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I'm attempting to write a function that prints strings the screen in C. It's for a boot loader so there are no external libraries or anything linked in. Here's my function:

```
void printString(const char* pStr) {
    while(*pStr) {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "movb 0x0e, %%ah\n"
            "movb %[c], %%al\n"
            "int $0x10\n"
            : 
            : [c] "r" (*pStr)
            : "ax"
        );
        ++pStr;
    }
}
```

When I run this, I don't get any errors in my VM. It just sits there with the cursor in the upper left corner of the screen. Any thoughts? I can produce an `objdump -d` if anyone thinks it will be helpful.

Comment: Probably because you aren't setting bx.

Comment: Exactly! What are the registers that have to be prepared before your call BIOS?

Comment: There are a number of online references for the old dos/bios interrupts (for example [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/rbinter/id/11/1.html)).  In this case, bh contains the page number.  Since I believe the default is page zero, unless bh just happens to be 0, the output will be written to a page that isn't being displayed.

Comment: Probably `"movb $0x0e, %%ah\n"` to indicate an immediate 0xe rather than memory at 0xe.

Comment: You can't use GCC, a 32-bit compiler, to reliably generate 16-bit code for boot loaders.

Comment: Nice call on the missing `$`. I'll have to see if loading `$0x0` into the `bx` reg fixes it. As far as using GCC, is that true even if I use `-march'? And, maybe it's because I'm new to building bootloaders/system tools but I've been compiling it as 32 bits and, aside from this function, it works just fine.

Comment: @dobafresh It won't work reliably. The system isn't in 32-bit mode at startup; your code is running in real mode (16-bit) and is *coincidentally* sort of working. But not the way you expect it to.

Comment: Okay, good info. So... if I create the GDT, enable A20, and set the PE bit and then call this function, compiled as a 32bit binary, it will work (all other errors aside).

Comment: The BIOS code that implements INT 0x10 doesn't work in protected mode, so you'd need to switch back to real-mode to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after some helpful comments, I may just go with full assembly. Something like

```
Print:
            push    %ax
            movb    $0x0E, %ah      # Set interrupt code
            movb    $0x00, %bh      # Set page #
.loop:
            lodsb                   # Load next char
            test    %al, %al        # Check for \0
            je      .done
            int     $0x10           # Call interrupt
            jmp     .loop

.done:
            pop     %ax
            ret
```

That should be 16-bit real mode compatible and can be assembled with GAS, which, as I understand it, works better than GCC for compiling 16-bit programs.

Comment: Make sure you have a `.code16` directive at the start of your source file so GAS generates 16-bit code.

Comment: You refer to the __helpful comments__ but you fail to include the setup of the BH, and in a graphics mode also the BL parameters. And why would you push and pop %EAX and not %AX in 16-bit real mode?

Comment: This code is working 100% fine for me. I guess there's two possibilities, either the values in `%bh` don't correspond to existing pages so it's just writing on the current page (unlikely) or `%bh` is zeroed by my computer on startup. I currently am not using `%rbx` or any of it's children so I think this is more likely. I'll add it to the snippet for completeness.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're missing the point.  The problem isn't your assembly code; the problem is that "int 10" is a BIOS

If you've already booted to an OS (e.g. Windows or Linux), then your x86 CPU is running in "protected mode"; and you probably don't have access to int 10 from user space ... unless something like a Windows command prompt emulates it for you.

As far as Linux/assembly programming in general, I *strongly* recommend this (free, on-line, *very* good) book:

[Programming from the Ground Up, Jonathan Bartlett](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/)

Thank you for clarifying that you're writing a "boot loader".  Strong suggestion1: boot your custom code from a USB stick, or create a virtual DOS floppy to boot a DOS VM (either VMWare or VBox VMs, for example).

Here are some tutorials:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader
- https://cs.au.dk/~sortie/dopsys/osdev/
- http://wiki.osdev.org/Rolling_Your_Own_Bootloader

Comment: Hmm, nooo. As I stated initially, I'm writing a bootloader. So I will be in real mode. The point of the function is to print out some debug/logging stuff to the screen while I boot into long mode. Once there, fine, I can't use it. I get that.

Comment: @paulsm4 You are wrong on this.  `int 10h` is, in fact, a BIOS interrupt accessible from real mode which is precisely where a boot loader starts.